# Java и самоподписанные SSL сертификаты

Tags: java, ssl

Стоит сервер - клиентское приложение , использующее в своей работе Java и TomCat. При соединении клиентского приложения с серверной частью по протоколу https используются самоподписанные SSL сертификаты . Используется версия JDK 8.92.
После настроек IE11 принял сертификаты как достоверные , в FF настроили исключения безопасности, в Java добавили сертификаты и прописали исключения для https адресов и портов сервера , но все равно , при входе на сервер через браузер, выскакивает предупреждение Java о ненадежности адреса.
Подскажите , есть ли какая то возможность или настройка , что бы избежать этого предупреждения.  Или подскажите - где и что можно почитать по этому вопросу . 
С Java знаком поверхностно ...